# Custom, Non-php sub directory added to Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

On the current site, we are attempting to add in a custom subdirectory on our Wordpress site that allows us to reference a 3rd party application. The code for this application is not written in php and isn't 'designed' for Wordpress.

Initially we added in a subdirectory and edited the .htaccess file to allow us to access the directory on our site, but it kept throwing a forbidden error. I spoke with our host (WPEngine) and they told us they no longer support .htaccess on their server and suggested that I parse the contents of the subdirectory to a page.

Does anyone know if this will even work if the contents of the custom subdirectory aren't php and there are a large quantity of files? Or is there another workaround that I'm not aware of?

For reference, here is the code written on the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/jobs/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting exactly? Just `/jobs/` perhaps? Or a file in that directory? What file are you expecting to be served from that directory? You won't normally need to add anything to `.htaccess` in order to serve files outside of WordPress. _Aside:_ The rule you added would actually have prevented WordPress from working due to the erroneous `OR` flag on the _condition_.

Comment: We would like to reference all the files in the /jobs/ subdirectory we created. This is technically an sdk app that parses data from the application (basically like a crm) they have that allows us to send jobs to our website. In the directory I don't see any sort of 'page', but an app.json file controls the setup. In the install docs they don't list referencing a page when doing an SFTP install.

Answer (score 0):

let try this:

**#1: Delete the addition .htaccess in the subdirectory**

**#2: change the permission of this directory to 644**

Comment: The question doesn't mention an additional `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory?